# How to add a text at end of each stopwords in a file

Tags: python

What im doing is append a string = "NOTRELATED" in each stopwords in the file. Here is my code but its not working:

```
stop_words  = set(stopwords.words('english'))
for line in word_tokenize(input_file):
    if line == stop_words:
        line = line.strip("\n") + " NOTRELATED\n"
        output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?  Please edit the question and add the error message and a better explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: the output file is empty means it didnt work but if i remove the condition "if line == stop_words:" its working. It adds NOTRELATED in each line in the file.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of answering in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
import nltk
for line in word_tokenize(input_file):
```

The `line` identifier is misnamed. You meant `word`.

```
if line == stop_words:
```

The equality test, `==`, is incorrect. You meant `if word in stop_words:`.

Comment: ive already tried that but it extract the stopwords and left the other lines.

Comment: Your comment suggests that, unlike the code in the Question, you really meant `if word not in stop_words:`.